# adb devices is returning an empty list

Tags: android, adb

I have been using my android sdk for more than two months on MAC. Suddenly today my system is giving an empty list for adb devices (for the same set of devices which used to be shown with results previously).

1. USB debugging options is on
2. Killed and started adb server many times
3. adb get-state is returning unknown.

Can somebody help me on what to do make my adb devices available and make it work?

Comment: Make sure the correct driver for your device is installed. The ones that Windows install does not have ADB support.

Comment: @leppie I am using Mac

Comment: Try installing [Motorola device Manager](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33419434/5420747) answer will help. But personally in the past I have had many issues with it being inconsistent, but 90% of the time, it is because of a bad cord (and once because of a bad computer port).

And for the sake of debugging or scripting, this command (found on the same page) might prove to be useful: `adb wait-for-device && adb <adb-command>`

### Edit:

Didn't realize how old of a post this was.. Haha hopefully this answer will help future googlers

Comment: It helped this googler, thanks~