# adb android devices list randomly empty

Tags: android, adb

I am developping an android application and I am having trouble getting adb to work reliably. Every now and then, my device (Samsung Galaxy S6) does not show in `adb devices` list anymore.

I have tried all solutions others suggested (restarting adb, restarting the device...), but none of them worked. Also, I seem to be the only one whose device is only *sometimes* not recognized.

I am using adb on ubuntu 14.04.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found out the problem was related to Chromium device inspector (`chrome://inspect/#devices`). Just closing the tab and reopening it did the trick. I'm using Chromium 45.0.2454.101. It was really driving me crazy ! Hopefully it spares someone else the trouble :)

Answer (score 1):

I see you found your solution, but for other's where this continues I had the same problem, until I simply 1. ran

```
adb wait-for-device
```

2. reconnected the device via usb
3. changed "Use USB for" "File Transfers"